# What is the range of that function?

Tags: functions

What is the range of the function $$f(x,y,z):=\left \{\frac{xyz}{xy+xz+yz} \right \}$$
over all the natural numbers  $x,\,y,\,z$ (Zero does not belong to the  naturals.), where $\{x\}$ stands for the fractional part of a real number $x$?

Comment: are you sure you want natural numbers, as opposed to positive real numbers? In the case of the former, it will be a subset of the rationals.

Comment: Thank you for the interest to the question. I am sure that the range is a subset of $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$. The question is  "What is that set?"

Comment: Thanks for that clarification,it helps knowing that they are rational. Why must it be less than 1? E.g. take $x=y=z=10$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range is all rationals in $(0,1).$  We have for $t\ge 1$
$$f(2k,2k,tk)=\frac{kt}{t+1}.\tag{1}$$
We first claim that for each $n>1$ the rational $\frac1n$ is in the range. To see this put $n=t+1$ so that $\gcd(n,t)=1$ and one may find $k$ for which $kt$ is $1$ mod $n.$ That is, $kt=1+nw$ for some positive integer $w$, and then the right side of $(1)$ becomes 
$$\frac{1+nw}{n}=\frac{1}{n}+w,$$ which has fractional part $\frac1n$ as desired.

Once we have obtained a value with fractional part $\frac1n$ we may go from the relation $f(x,y,z)=m+\frac1n$ to the relation $f(kx,ky,kz)=km+\frac{k}{n}$ and thus we have also $\frac kn$ in the range, for $1 \le k < n.$

*Added:* For an explicit triple to cover $k/n$ where $n\ge 2$ and $0<k<n$ the above can be worked out to get
$$f(2k(n-1),2k(n-1),k(n-1)^2)=\frac{k}{n}+k(n-2)$$
which has fractional part $\frac kn.$ Note also that using $k=n$ here gives a fractional part $0$, so that the actual range of $f$ is the set of rationals in $[0,1).$ [Thanks to @user64494 for pointing out $0$ is in the range.]

Comment: @ coffeemath: And zero.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, it can achieve zero since it is fractional part and one can achieve some positive integers. +1 on comment.